# Not able to access Checkbox values in IE9

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

I have an asp.net web page where i have a checkbox control inside gridview control as under

```
    <asp:GridView ID="grdMergeCoverage" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">

     <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField>
             <ItemTemplate>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chkSelectStream" onclick="OnSelectionChanged(this);"          
testrunid='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"TestRunId") %>'
checked='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CodeCoverageRequired") %>' 
servername='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ServerName") %>'
  runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And the **OnSelectionChanged** function is as under

```
function OnSelectionChanged(id) 
{            
        alert(id.testrunid);
        alert(id.servername);
        alert(id.checked);
}
```

In IE8 , I am able to get the value for testrunid,servername while in IE 9, it is coming as NULL.

What is the problem and how can i get the value in all the cases?

Comment: is there any error showed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get custom attributes you should use the [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.getAttribute) method.

Like so: `id.getAttribute("servername")`.

The way you used to get the value before is non-standard and not always supported.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the asp checkbox and add the attribute to it on the gridview rowitembound event. it will fire....